# Return specific object from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a ArrayList with thousands of properties with many variables(including city). I need access/return only the properties from a specific city e.g all properties from Surrey. How do i get them?

I know how to search for them, by doing city.values("Surrey"). But I do not know how output the values.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This question is missing quite a lot of content in order to be compatible with proper question standards.

Comment: I havn't tried anything, I have properties inside my array list with variables such as City,price, owner etc and I need to search through the arraylist and output only the properties in surrey. Sorry I am really bad at explaining this and using correct terminology as i am new to java.

Comment: Can you show your ArrayList, or a part of it?

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: ***"I havn't tried anything,"***... Nobody is going to do your homework for you. If you have tried something..enlighten us such we become a participant in your quest for a solution to the stated problem..

Comment: by that I meant that i couldn't figure anything out, I've been stuck on this for two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to search in your AirbnbListing list. You can use [Java Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). Use the `filter` method for that:

```
List<AirbnbListing> matchingListings = listings.stream()
    .filter(l -> "Surrey".equals(l.getCity()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want a list of all cities, you can use the `map` method:

```
List<String> matchingListings = listings.stream()
    .map(l -> l.getCity())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Additionally [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) is an official Java stream explanation tutorial.

Comment: List<AirbnbListing> matchingListings = listings.stream().filter(l -> neighbourhood.equals("London")).collect(Collectors.toList());   Does this also work?

Comment: What is the `neighbourhood` variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 or higher there is following option:
`list.stream().filter(x -> "Berlin".equals(x.getCity())); //This filters the list and returns a list with city = Berlin.`

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.